# php error query was empty

Tags: php, mysql

You can see I can successfully redirect values from one to this page.

```
$shipping_first_name = $_POST['shipping_first_name'];
$shipping_address= $_POST['shipping_address'];
$shipping_city = $_POST['shipping_city'];
$shipping_state = $_POST['shipping_state'];
$shipping_zip_code = $_POST['shipping_zip_code'];
$shipping_phone = $_POST['shipping_phone'];
$shipping_mobile =$_POST['shipping_mobile'];
$Shipping_email = $_POST['shipping_email'];

echo $shipping_address,$Shipping_email; // now this line shows contains but
```

Order entry: this query returns nothing.
Error is query was empty. What do I do?

```
$qurey1 = 'INSERT INTO ecomm_orders
(order_id,order_date, customer_id, cost_subtotal,
cost_total, shipping_first_name, shipping_address, shipping_city, shipping_state,
shipping_zipcode, shipping_phone, shipping_mobile, shipping_email)
VALUES
(NULL,"'.$now.'",'.$customer_id.',0.00,0.00,"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_first_name,$db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_address, $db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_city, $db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_state, $db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_zip_code, $db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_phone, $db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_mobile, $db).'",
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($Shipping_email, $db).'")';
mysql_query($query1,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$order_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

Prior to this query I run query to populate customer table successfully, using same method.
But what could be wrong?

Comment: May be just a typo, but you have inconsistent spelling of: `qurey1`, and later `query1`...

Comment: As a side note, if you use prepared statements, you can avoid all the `mysql_real_escape_string` and clean up the `VALUES` portion of the query.

Comment: thanks i spent hours to find out what was the prob. thanks

Comment: what is prepared statments?
i m kind of fresher in php field. may b i m using this thing what it is?
[:)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quote rather than double quote to wrap values.

```
\''.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_address, $db).'\',
```

Instead of

```
"'.mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_address, $db).'",
```

Comment: thanks for help and i wil try using single quote .its just that i am used to double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming all the variables placed into your MySQL query are not empty...  Change the "$qurey1 =" (variable you put your query into) to "$query1 =".  I believe you simply have a typo.